# Joomla 3.5 Module Developing Backend XML Structure

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla3.0

I try to make my first Joomla Module. This module can at the moment output 4 boxes. I implement the 4 boxes manualy in the XML and in the template file. And i difine the variables like this:

```
'Title1' => $params->get('devServiceTitle1'),
'Icon1' => $params->get('devServiceIcon1'),
'Content1' => $params->get('devServiceContent1'),

'Title2' => $params->get('devServiceTitle2'),
'Icon2' => $params->get('devServiceIcon2'),
'Content2' => $params->get('devServiceContent2'),

'Title3' => $params->get('devServiceTitle3'),
'Icon3' => $params->get('devServiceIcon3'),
'Content3' => $params->get('devServiceContent3'),

'Title4' => $params->get('devServiceTitle4'),
'Icon4' => $params->get('devServiceIcon4'),
'Content4' => $params->get('devServiceContent4'),
```

This looks for me very ugly and unclean... And at last i want to make a dropdown field, in the XML in that the user can select other counts of Boxes... 3, 4, 6 and 8... And this is not all. I need to make a Selection for the Template file to... I search sience 2 weeks in google, but i dont find any answere to my questions. so i ask here.

Comment: I would suggest asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com), which is the dedicated Stack Exchange network for Joomla related questions

Answer (score 0):

You want to add this fields in the module back-end?

if yes than You have  to add like below.

```
            <field name="boxwidth" type="text" default="300" label="Box Width" description="Like Box Width" />
            <field name="boxheight" type="text" default="300" label="Box Height" description="Like Box Height" />

            <field name="colorscheme" type="list" default="light" label="Color scheme" description="Color Scheme">
                <option value="light">Light</option>
                <option value="dark">Dark</option>
            </field>
            <field name="showfaces" type="list" default="true" label="Show Faces" description="Show Faces">
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
                <option value="False">No</option>
            </field>
            <field name="showheader" type="list" default="true" label="Show Header" description="Show Header">
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
                <option value="False">No</option>
            </field>
            <field name="showborder" type="list" default="true" label="Show Border" description="Show Border">
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
                <option value="false">No</option>
            </field>


        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

if you want to create four fields on site side just create simple html form on module file.

Comment: i know the form types. thjat is not the problem. but when i select by "grid" the value 4.. then i have to load another tempalte file, and to display in the backend the 4 edit fields. when i chose by grid the value 2 then i need again another template and only 2 edit fields.